# How do i change the order of the fields on the email notification sent from a task list after it is assigned?

Tags: email

How do i change the order of the fields on the email notification sent from a task list after it is assigned? I need to set the order of the fields. Thank  you in advance for your help! SharePoint 2010 [image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to `List settings`, click on the `Column ordering` link in `Columns` section. There you will find the ordering of the columns which is used in all default forms (display, new, edit) and in email notifications (alerts or task notifications), and you can change it by choosing the appropriate values in combo boxes.

The important thing to note is that when you change the ordering there, all mentioned forms will follow the new ordering.

Answer (score 0):

Tip: you will need to disable content type management (Allow management of content types? = No) in order to change the column order. Once you have the column order to your liking you may re-enable content type management.